# javascript file not working when linked from HTML

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom

so I feel(and hope) this is pretty simple. I am new to javascript and am trying to get this working. When I link to my external .js file from my html it does not function. However, when entering the script code directly into my HTML it DOES work.

Here is the js file:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#flip").click(function(){
    $("#panel").slideToggle("slow");
  });
});
```

This is the index.html file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>slidepanel test</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css"/>
</head>

<body>


<div id="flip">Click to slide the panel down or up</div>
<div id="panel">Hello world!</div>

</body>
</html>
```

and this is the CSS:

```
#panel,#flip
{
padding:5px;
text-align:center;
background-color:#e5eecc;
border:solid 1px #c3c3c3;
}
#panel
{
padding:50px;
display:none;
}
```

Comment: I'm going to go out on a limb about this, but I am assuming your `script.js` file IS your jQuery file and you are adding your code to the top of the file, reason if you add the code into the document itself it DOES work. If that is the case then move your code to the end of the `script.js` file. OR you can make a separate file for your custom code and load it after the jQuery file.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You are using jQuery, but it doesn't seem like you have included it. Add this to your HEAD element

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thank you so much, cannot believe I missed that!

Answer (score 2):

You need to import jQuery.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 2):

Actually, i had a problem like this and i tried the code below.

```
<head>
<meta charset="ISO-8859-1">
<title></title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
</head>
```

Comment: Is this an answer or comment for needing further help?

Answer (score 1):

I have similar problem.
Below is a code in two files which generates only white empty page,
no errors are reported executing code, what is the problem?

index.html file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Three.js</title>
    <style type = "text/css">
        html, body {margin: 0; padding: 0; overflow: hidden}
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div id = "webgl"></div>
    <script src = "/lib/three.js"></script>
    <script src="./main.js"></script>
</html>
```

main.js file:

```
function init() {
    var scene = new THREE.Scene();

    var box = getBox(1, 1, 1);
    var plane = getPlane(4);

    box.position.y = box.geometry.parameters.height/2;
    plane.rotation.x = Math.PI/2;

    scene.add(box);
    scene.add(plane);

    var camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(
        45,
        window.innerWidth/window.innerHeight,
        1,
        1000
    );

    camera.position.x = 1;
    camera.position.y = 2;
    camera.position.z = 5;

    camera.lookAt(new THREE.Vector3(0, 0, 0));

    var renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
    renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
    document.getElementById('webgl').appendChild(renderer.domElement);
    renderer.render(
        scene,
        camera 
    );
}

function getBox(w, h, d) {
    var geometry = new THREE.BoxGeometry(w, h, d);
    var material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({
        color: 0x00ff00
    });
    var mesh = new THREE.Mesh(
        geometry,
        material 
    );

    return mesh;
}

function getPlane(size) {
    var geometry = new THREE.PlaneGeometry(size, size);
    var material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({
        color: 0xff0000,
        side: THREE.DoubleSide
    });
    var mesh = new THREE.Mesh(
        geometry,
        material 
    );

    return mesh;
}

init();
```

Answer (score 0):

You dont have jquery in your `<head>` section. Add it before you add `scripts.js`. Only then will your code work.

```
<head>
  <title>slidepanel test</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css"/>

  <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>

</head>
```

If you're testing this in your local machine, add a `http` to the src or download your own copy of jQuery.

And just as a sidenote, its always better to add `stylesheets` before your `js` files.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you're missing jQuery. Include it before you include your own JavaScript code.

Answer (score 0):

Your script contains jQuery.In order to use it, you have 2 options:

### 1. Download it to your web page:

- Dowload the production version from [jQuery.com](http://jquery.com/download/)
- In the `<head></head>` section add: `<script src="jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>`

### 2. Include jQuery from a CDN:

- You can use Google's CDN by adding the following to the`<head></head>` section: 
  `<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>`

Answer (score 0):

I also had the same problem until I changed the location of the  line to the end of the code just before the closing  tag and it worked. In my opinion, being at the header the functionalities get overwiritten.