# Why is the Javascript not loading on this WordPress plugin?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, wordpress

I have looked over carefully at the scripts file for a WordPress plugin I am developing and I also looked at a similar post:

[javascript file not working when linked from HTML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17505563/javascript-file-not-working-when-linked-from-html)

but the answer above has not worked either. I am not sure why the javascript file is not loading.

Here is the includes/newsletter-subscriber-scripts.php:

```
<?php

// Add Scripts
function ns_add_scripts(){
        wp_enqueue_style('ns-main-style', plugins_url().'/newsletter-subscriber/css/style.css');
        wp_enqueue_script('ns-main-script', plugins_url().'/newsletter-subscriber/js/main.js');
}

add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'ns_add_scripts');
```

Here is the javascript file that is not loading in /newsletter-subscriber/js/main.js:

```
alert('Linked');
```

Comment: What do the developer tools in your browser say about it?

Comment: @SamiKuhmonen, the Console is completely blank.

Comment: And the network part which shows what it tries to load and the status codes?

Comment: @SamiKuhmonen, no javascript is loading from the plugin and everything is 200 with the exception of the jquery which is 307.

Answer (score 0):

Did you check it out that its enqueuing in front end you can see script tag in your HTML output? of its coming than might be your browser java-script is off.
check it or you can add link to your site so than someone can debug it

thank you

Comment: I didn't test it, but I think it had to do with the custom WordPress theme I was testing it with because when I tried the plugin on another custom WordPress theme I created it worked fine.